# Профилирование golang

Tags: golang, профилирование

При старте программы делаю:

```
    if *profiler != "" {
    fprof, err := os.Create(*profiler)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Can't open profiler file:", err)
        return
    }
    pprof.StartCPUProfile(fprof)
    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
}
```

Программа работает 2 минуты, потом штатно завершается. Нагрузка на процессор 30-40%. Файл профайла весит 695K.
При попытке посмотреть кто жрёт процессор получаю:

```
go tool pprof -text sm-1.prof 
22.63s of 22.63s total (  100%)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    22.63s   100%   100%     22.63s   100%
```

т.е. никакой детализации.

Go 1.5.1, OS Linux x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go tool pprof` надо вызывать, указывая бинарь в качестве первого аргумента. Т.е.

```
go tool pprof ./sm-1 sm-1.pprof
```