# golang pprof heap пустой файл

Tags: golang

Добавил pprof в web сайт:

```
import "net/http/pprof"

r.GET("/debug/pprof/", pprof.Index)
r.GET("/debug/pprof/cmdline", pprof.Cmdline)
r.GET("/debug/pprof/profile", pprof.Profile)
r.GET("/debug/pprof/symbol", pprof.Symbol)
r.GET("/debug/pprof/trace", pprof.Trace)

r.Run(":8080")
```

Перехожу на /debug/pprof/

вижу такое:

```
/debug/pprof/

profiles:
0   block
7   goroutine
876 heap
0   mutex
6   threadcreate

full goroutine stack dump
```

захожу на /debug/pprof/profile
через 30 сек сохраняется браузером файл

go tool pprof "сохраненный файл" 
все  гуд работает...

НО /debug/pprof/heap не работает (через curl сохраняет пустой файл, а через go tool pprof test http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/haep - пишет http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/heap: parsing profile: empty input file
failed to fetch any source profiles) хотя видно что считает... почему? что может быть не так? как запустить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Профилирование golang](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469353/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-golang)

Comment: @Ainar-G короче не понял ответа пробовал с указанием бинарника и без, проблема не решилась и в вопросе я писал с указанием бинарника, не понимаю ответа! go tool pprof test http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/haep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно дополнительно зарегистрировать обработчики, которые отдаёт `pprof.Handler`:

```golang
router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/", pprof.Index)
router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/cmdline", pprof.Cmdline)
router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/profile", pprof.Profile)
router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/symbol", pprof.Symbol)
router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/trace", pprof.Trace)

// N.B.
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/block", pprof.Handler("block"))
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/goroutine", pprof.Handler("goroutine"))
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/heap", pprof.Handler("heap"))
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/threadcreate", pprof.Handler("threadcreate"))
```

Неочевидно, но должно заработать.